# Order of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_4$.  Then one can conclude that $G/[G, G]$ (the abelianization of $G$) is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$ because these are both abelian groups.  This group has order 4.  My book says it has order 8...is this a typo?

Comment: what book are you using?

Comment: "This group has order two"... **what** group are you talking about? I see no group of order two in your whole question.

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$. It's a handout from my class.

Comment: Sorry I meant order 4.  The handout says it's order 8.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing the order, i.e. size, of a group (in this case 8), with the element with the highest order ( (1,1) and (1,3) both have order 4).

Comment: Yep. @NickC has it right. I rather hate the overuse of the term "order" in this context. I prefer to say the cardinality of a group to mean its number of elements and strictly use "order" to mean the order of an element.

Comment: By $\mathbb Z_2 *\mathbb Z_4$, did you mean $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_4$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You're right I was confusing order of a group with order of an element. How unintuitive!

Answer (score 1):

The group does have order $8$. You seem to be confusing the order and the exponent of a group: the order of a group is just its cardinality, i.e. the number of elements. The exponent of a group is the smallest natural number $n$ such that for all elements $g$ of the group we have $g^n=e$, or -- if such a number does not exist -- $\infty$.

The group ${\bf Z}_2\oplus {\bf Z}_4$ has order $8$ and exponent $4$.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of $Z2⊕Z4$ can be represented as $(0, 0), (0, 1) (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), and (1, 3)$.  It has order $2*4= 8$.